# Query nodes from multiple specific paths in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm playing with cypher and I have some simple aggregation going on for me.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_CAR]->(n:Car)
RETURN n, count(p)

MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_APARTMENT]->(n:Apartment)
RETURN n, count(p)

MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_HOUSE]->(n:House)
RETURN n, count(p)
```

The problem is that I have to make 3 trips to the database to get all those results together. The problematic thing about that is that those queries are the last `MATCH` statement in a much bigger chain. Like this:

```
MATCH (:City { Id: 10})<-[:LIVES_IN]-(p:Person)
WITH p
MATCH ...
WITH p
MATCH ...
WITH p
MATCH ...
WITH p
MATCH ...
WITH p
MATCH p-[:HAS_CAR]->(n:Car)
RETURN n, count(p)
```

After all those `MATCH ... WITH` statements, only a few person nodes are matched so the last part of the query is very fast, but the initial part is not. I can't help but think that this could be improved because all three queries share a lot of statements.

I came up with this:

```
...
MATCH p-[:HAS_CAR|HAS_APARTMENT|HAS_HOUSE]->(n)
RETURN n, labels(n), count(p)
```

And I can work with that. But what if I wanted to mix in something like this:

```
MATCH p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person)-[:HAS_BIKE]->(n:Bike)
RETURN n, count(p)
```

Or even:

```
MATCH p-[:KNOWS]->(:Person)-[:HAS_BIKE|HAS_BOAT]->(n)
RETURN n, labels(n), count(p)
```

Can all of this be done in a single query and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you need to use collections instead of rows to merge aggregation queries together and pass them along. This strategy might help... For example:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_CAR]->(car:Car)
WITH car, count(p) carCount
WITH collect({car:car, count:carCount}) as carCounts
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_APARTMENT]->(n:Apartment)
WITH n, count(p) as apartmentCount, carCounts
RETURN collect({apartment:n, count:apartmentCount}) as apartmentCounts, carCounts
```

Update (see comments)--this lets you pass along the results of a filter and do a quick id lookup to find them again:

```
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.name = "John" // or whatever else you need to filter on
WITH collect(id(p)) as pids
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_CAR]->(car:Car)
WHERE id(p) IN pids
WITH car, count(p) carCount, pids
WITH collect({car:car, count:carCount}) as carCounts, pids
MATCH (p)-[:HAS_APARTMENT]->(n:Apartment)
WHERE id(p) IN pids
WITH n, count(p) as apartmentCount, carCounts
RETURN collect({apartment:n, count:apartmentCount}) as apartmentCounts, carCounts
```

Comment: Because you are not passing `p` in the `WITH car, count(p) as carCount`, the statement `MATCH (p:Person)-[:HAS_APARTMENT]->(n:Apartment)` is not respecting previous filtering chain and matches **all** Person nodes. If you add `p` like `WITH p, car, count(p) as carCount` then the `count(p)` aggregation is not correct. Is there any way to solve this?